# Anyone know of a free date and *time* ASP.NET custom control

Tags: asp.net, datetime, calendar, custom-controls

Every time I have to build a form with a `DateTime` field I try to find a decent free custom control - I always fail.

I cannot figure out why it isn't built in the .NET but let's forget about for a minute and concentrate on my question :D

Anyone got one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two separate TextBoxes, one for date and one for time.  For the date one, use the ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit [Calendar](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) control, as someone else pointed out.

For the time TextBox, have a look at the [MaskedEditExtender](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) control in the same toolkit.  You can set it to display **:**:__ AM/PM and let the user fill in.  You can fill with zeros if they just type "3p" and tab out.

To use it, you need a TextBox.  You set the MaskedEditExtender's TargetControlID to the TextBox's ID.  Here are some attributes you'll need to set in the MaskedEditExtender tag for time entry:

```
Mask="99:99"
AutoCompleteValue="00:00"
AcceptAMPM="true"
MaskType="Time"
```

Also, if you get a weird FindControl-related error, make sure that your MaskedEditExtenders all have IDs set.

Comment: sweet looks like what I'm after nice an simple, really prefer not to use third party stuff if I can help it.

Answer (score 2):

Just combine these two

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/

http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html

jQuery is where it's at!

Comment: I agree jQuery is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Calendar control](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) extender from the [MS AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/), I really like it.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick Google and came across this one...

http://www.softcomplex.com/products/tigra_calendar/demo1.html

Looks like it supports dates and times, and it appears to be free.

Comment: javascript not a .NET custom control

Comment: Does it really make a server hit every time you click on something in the calendar?  That's lame.  I prefer a client-side solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've had fairly good luck with this one:

http://www.eworldui.net/

Comment: i don't think it had a time component

Comment: They do: http://www.eworldui.net/CustomControls/TimePicker.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This works nicely indeed.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="startDate" autocomplete="off" />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender 
    ID="defaultCalendarExtender" 
    runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="startDate" />
<asp:TextBox ID="startTime" runat="server" Columns="8"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender 
    ID="startTime_MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server" 
    Enabled="True" 
    TargetControlID="startTime" 
    MaskType="Time" 
    AutoCompleteValue="09:00"
    Mask="99:99"
    AcceptAMPM="true">
</ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender>
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator 
    ID="MaskedEditValidator1" 
    runat="server" 
    ControlExtender="startTime_MaskedEditExtender1"
    ControlToValidate="startTime" 
    IsValidEmpty="False"
    EmptyValueMessage="Time is required"
    InvalidValueMessage="Time is invalid"
    Display="Dynamic"
    TooltipMessage="Input a time"
    EmptyValueBlurredText="*"
    InvalidValueBlurredMessage="Check time">
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Ra-Ajax Calendar control](http://ra-ajax.org/samples/Ajax-Calendar.aspx) will actually be released the upcoming Friday (28th of November 2008) with Time support (two textboxes between the Today button and the dates)

Ra-Ajax is LGPL licensed and Free of Charge to use...